# Use the Checkstyle API without providing a java.io.File

Tags: java, checkstyle

Is there a way to use the Checkstyle API without providing a `java.io.File`?
Our app already has the file contents in memory (these aren't read from a local file, but from another source), so it
seems inefficent to me to have to create a temporary file and write the in-memory contents to it just to throw it away.
I've looked into using in-memory file systems to circumvent this, but it seems `java.io.File` is always bound to the
actual file system. Obviously I have no way of testing whether or not performance would be better, just wanted to ask if Checkstyle supports such a use case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clean way to do this. I recommend creating an issue at Checkstyle expanding more on your process and asking for a way to integrate it with Checkstyle.

Files are needed for our support of caching, as we skip over reading and processing a file if it is in the cache and it has not changed since the last run. The cache process is intertwined which is why no non-file route exists. Even without a file, Checkstyle processes the contents of files through `FileText`, which again needs a `File` for just a file name reference and lines of the file in a `List`.